# Can't upgrade SQLite model to EF Core 2 due to AddForeignKeyOperation

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to upgrade my app to ASP.NET Core 2, with EF Core 2 (and SQLite), in other words `netcoreapp2.0`. I followed the [upgrade guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade).

I also recreated migrations, and noticed the new ones are quite different from the ones I remember from 1.1 (different commands sent to the db, different syntax, etc). But my model is the same, and after generating migrations, everything compiles properly.

BUT, when I try to create the db programmatically using `context.Database.Migrate();`, or manually on the CLI using `dotnet ef database update`, I get

> System.NotSupportedException: SQLite does not support this migration operation ('AddForeignKeyOperation'). For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723262.

However, I don't use the `AddForeignKeyOperation` command anywhere in my solution (I searched for it). I searched my migration files, and they don't use that command.

I'm sure it's something basic, but I can't track it down. What could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not deleting all migrations.

I had the "initial" migration, then migration1, migration2, etc. The initial migration is from the template, so it had Identity/roles/users/etc. So I left that one alone and deleted/recreated the other ones only (i.e. the ones with my domain model).

Well it turns out that when I deleted ALL migrations, and recreated them, I stopped getting that error.

That error is confusing and poorly worded, and has nothing to do with the problem. Hope this helps someone else.